# How to set Input for argument of mass actions

Tags: massaction

My case: I have the mass action for a selected products to make some math operations with a prices. At first step I have the "Change prices" action and the selecting on it gives me the mass actions with needed operation (+,-, * and so on).

> $operations = Mage::getSingleton('op/operations')->getOptionArray();

```
    array_unshift($operations, [
        'label' => '',
        'value' => ''
        ]);

    $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('Change price', array(
    'label' => Mage::helper('op')->__('Change price'),
    'url' => $this->getUrl('*/*/massPrices', array(
        '_current' => true
    )),
    'additional' => array(
        'visibility' => array(
            'name' => 'operations',
            'type' => 'select',
            'class' => 'required-entry',
            'label' => Mage::helper('op')->__('Change price'),
            'values' => $operations
        )
    )
));
```

But in order to make some math operations I need to get argument for user's input. To do this I try  to repeat `getMassactionBlock`from previous step with new label and `type=text`. yes, it really gives me text input, but I'd like to get only after the second mass action (with math operations) will be selected.

Thx for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest redirecting to a landing page with a form for price adjustment input before you head to the massPricesAction.

What I mean is, you can go

```
$this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('Change price', array(
'label' => Mage::helper('op')->__('Change price'),
'url' => $this->getUrl('*/*/inputMassPriceAdjustment', array(
    '_current' => true
)),
```

in your massaction, then you set up a custom page in your controller, like

```
public function inputMassPriceAdjustmentAction() {

if (!$this->_validateFormKey()) {
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
        return;
    }

if($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
    $params = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
    if(isset($params['product_ids']) && !empty($params['product_ids'])) {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('price_adjustment_form')->setProductIds($params['product_ids']);
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
else {
    $this->_redirect('*/*/');
        return;
}
}
```

finally you can set up your form, collect the price adjustment input (and maybe other data you might want to change) and post the whole shebang to your original massPricesAction(). You might want to put the product_ids into hidden fields temporarily.

Hope this helps ;)

Comment: Nice approach, thx!